# I am not getting customized UI of ThemeRoller in mobile for phonegap android?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, themeroller

I have customized theme have downloaded theme, added as reference but my mobile UI is not displaying me my custom theme :

Here is the custom theme:[ThemeRoller Custom Theme](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/?ver=1.3.2&style_id=20130802-3)
and added it as in phonegap Android  but no result:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/converterThemeFinald.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/converterThemeFinald.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div data-role="page" id="converterListPage">

   <div data-role="header">
    <h1>UNIT CONVERTER</h1>
   </div>
   <div data-role="content">
      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
       <li><a href="#"  id="tempButton">TEMPERATURE</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" id="weightButton">WEIGHT</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" id="currencyButton">CURRENCY CONVERTER</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" id="speedButton">SPEED CONVERSION</a></li>
      </ul>


   </div>
 </div>
```

How can I get my custom theme of theme Roller in my App please help me
SCREEN SHOTS AFTER FOLLOWING ANSWER of Gajorates:
[image: screen shots]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are blindly following jQuery Mobile theme-roller tutorial how to apply new theme. You have two new theme swatches A and B. And you are including them before you initialize full jQuery Mobile CSS who also has original A and B swatches. Because full jQuery Mobile CSS was initialized last its CSS will be applied over your custom one.

You can fix this problem in 2 different ways:

1. Remove this line:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
   ```

   #### HTML example:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
           <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
           <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css" /> 
           <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
           <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>    
       </head>
       <body>
           <div data-role="page" id="index">
               <div data-role="header">
                   <h1>Index page</h1>
               </div>

               <div data-role="content">

               </div>
           </div>    
       </body>
   </html>
   ```

   To test this just replace test.css with your custom CSS.
2. Or you should initialize your CSS last:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/converterThemeFinald.min.css" />
   ```

Comment: but its removing all data-clear-btn = "true"  attribute i m not gettting  UI properly and even on select box "dropdown arrow" UI is not clear scrren shots attached in my edited post

Comment: I cant help you unless you tell me what solution have you uses 1 or 2?

Comment: i m using 1st option and getting improper UI have already added image in my edited question

Comment: @Gajorates i m using 1st option but still there is no clear button after adding data-clear-btn="true"