# Phonegap jQueryMobile Theme on android

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, themeroller

Here I am and I need your help. I've been working on Android applications for a few months and today the enterprise asks me to use Phonegap as to create a hybride app.

I'd like to try some themes with [ThemeRoller](http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/) but when I try to input the files in my app, something goes wrong : the theme doesn't apply !
Well, this is partly true because if I look at the app using my web Browser, the theme applies perfectly but when I build & run the app on my phone, the text will appear as if there weren't any CSS.

Why only on the phone ? I've been looking around the web and even found [That link !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012517/i-am-not-getting-customized-ui-of-themeroller-in-mobile-for-phonegap-android) It's exactly the same question as mine but I tried what worked for him and nothing good happened to me, no new result, no change at all.

So here is the header of my index.html :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery Mobile: Theme Download</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="web-holo/AndroidHoloDarkLight.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="roboto/fonts.css" />
</head>
```

And here is the website I found the theme on : [That Web Site](http://teusink.blogspot.nl/2012/09/android-holo-theme-for-jquery-mobile-111.html)
I input the Theme folder in WWW but anyway the code found it since the Desktop web browser displays it correctly...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Maybe something to do with internet access restriction ? (at least for your js files)

Comment: This may indeed, I'm gonna check it out and keep you updated, thanks !

Comment: Take a look to the whitelist guide page and let us know if it solves your problem http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: You're right this was the whitelist ! Thank you so much =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer thanks to Aliassse !

The probelm was the [WhiteList](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide) !
I was creating my app from a basic application found on the web which "www/config.xml" file was modified.
Indeed I could see at the end of the xml file :

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
```

This means that the app can only access to local pages, not online. And I needed to access pages like :

> http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js

So in order to solve that, I changed the broken line to :

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

I built the app again, run it on my device and it worked ! A heavy thanks to Aliassse for being that fast and efficient !