# Themeroller header and Phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, themeroller

I'm developing an android app in html with the help of Phonegap.

I made my own app theme with [Themeroller](http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/)

The theme shows up great in IE and Chrome however not in my mobile. The Themeroller theme I made gets replaced with a standard theme. I'm not the only one and many other have had the same problem, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016253/phonegap-jquerymobile-theme-on-android?lq=1). However, by reading the solutions I have not been able to produce any own solutions.

I would like some help to rewrite my code.

This is my code.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/Jakt.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that is the solution to my problem:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jakt.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.3.min.css" /> 
  <script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script> 
  <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
```

I removed `<meta charset="utf-8" />` since it would not display scandinavian letters correctly.
I also made the files local although the code above works fine with urls.

Answer (score 0):

When including jQueryMobile Themeroller you have to include a file with the base css: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css and not the standard one. This file is downloaded from the site with your custom css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>jQuery Mobile page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/my-custom-theme.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.3.min.css" /> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script> 

</head>
```

Your code should be:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/Jakt.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I remove "<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">" as you did in your code my browser will not load the theme correctly.

Comment: Have you put instead http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css ?

Comment: I tried now. Unfortuently when I do that it does not even load standard theme.

Comment: Does is downloaded properly? Inspect with console if all files are correctly downloaded. You can download files locally if it fails.

Comment: I think I'm near the solution now, give me some minutes and I'll rewrite my code above.